# Reading Windows Environment Variable (Encoding/Charset Issue)

Tags: java

what I wanna do is read the Windows environment variable %APPDATA%. I have some severe problems with Umlauts though e.g. if APDATA is set to `"ÄÄÄ"` I ll get sth like `"'''"`.

Here is my code:

```
final Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /C echo %APPDATA%");
final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String buffer;
if((buffer = br.readLine()) != null) {
    return buffer;
}
```

If I print out

```
String encoding_system = System.getProperty("file.encoding");
```

I'm getting `Cp1252`. I tried to tell the InputStreamReader the system encoding, but nothing changes.

Answer (score 1):

That's a brittle way of trying to get an environment variable's value. You're better off using `System.getEnv()`. This will return a `Map<String, String>` instance linking environment variable names to their values.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you're right but I forgot to post that in this project I m still using Java 1.4 :(

Comment: @user734535 Well I'll be... It really was only introduced in 1.5. That's annoying. Not sure what's going on then. Encoding for console output tends to be problematic in my experience.

Comment: I temporary used Java 1.6. with System.getEnv("APPDATA") but I am ending up with the same encoding problem. After that I tried to convert the String with string.getBytes(<Charset>) iteration over all Charset, but none of them supply the correct string

Comment: @user734535 How was the variable set in the first place? Maybe it actually has an incorrect value because the input was wrongly encoded or misinterpreted...

Comment: I have set in in the Windows system preferences environment variables. Actually I am working with a variable called TEST set to "Hällo".